# MYSQL -Incorrect Syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
WHILE x > 1 DO
SET x = x - 1;    
SET totalTime =  SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) / 24), ' days ',

MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), 24), ' hrs ',

MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), ' minutes ') AS total_Time
```

I don't see why I am having a syntax error?

It is part of a bigger procedure but is pointing to this aas being incorrect

Error message:
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) / 24,' days',' at line 11

and totalTime is declared as a VARCHAR(50)

Comment: For starters there's no `end while;` (but that might be caused by the fact that you're just quoting part of a procedure).  And what's the error you get?

Comment: what error do you get? please add the errormessage.

Comment: 1064 in general means some error in terms of so called "reserved words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `SELECT` keyword if you are setting the value of a variable.

```
SET totalTime = CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) / 24), ' days ',

MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), 24), ' hrs ',

MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), ' minutes ');
```

If you want to use the `SELECT` keyword, then the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) / 24), ' days ',

MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), 24), ' hrs ',

MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), ' minutes ') INTO totalTime;
```

Take note of the added code `INTO variable name`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be, because `FLOOR`, `HOUR`, `TIMEDIFF` etc need a surrounding `SELECT` like:

```
WHILE x > 1 DO
SET x = x - 1;    
SET totalTime =  SELECT CONCAT( SELECT FLOOR( SELECT HOUR( SELECT TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) / 24), ' days ',

SELECT MOD( SELECT HOUR( SELECT TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), 24), ' hrs ',

SELECT MINUTE(SELECT TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), ' minutes ') AS total_Time
```

Otherwise it may not interprete this Words as kind of function calls and throw "reserved words" error. (I assume the `END WHILE;` is already somewhere in your code.)
Please check it and let me know.